# C : scanf or wscanf, I can't print correctly the accented character

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to printf a character/String given by the user with accents, but this doesn't work.
After consulting a lot of forums, I think that `<wchar.h>` can solve my problem, but I have the same result.

```
main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    char buffer[50], choix;

    printf("CHAR\nEntrez un char : ");
    scanf(" %c", &choix);
    printf("%c\n", choix);
    getchar();

    printf("Entrez votre éùàç prénom : ");
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    getchar();
    printf("%s\n\n", buffer);

    wchar_t wbuffer[50], wchoix;

    printf("WCHAR\nEntrez un char : ");
    wscanf(L" %lc", &wchoix);
    wprintf(L"%lc\n", wchoix);
    getchar();

    wprintf(L"Entrez votre éùàç prénom : ");
    wscanf(L"%ls", wbuffer);
    getchar();
    wprintf(L"%ls\n\n", wbuffer);
    
    _getch();
}
```

The result was (on Windows 10 or Windows 11):
[result code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3IDJ.png)

All of the 'literal printf' calls are working correctly, so what happened to the data from stdin?
What am I missing?

Comment: Note that using just `main()` has not been valid in standard C for the whole of this millennium (all your life?).  You should use `int main()` — or, preferably, `int main(void)`.   Since you are learning C now, you should learn modern C — not the antiquated C90 standard C that permitted you to omit `int`.

Comment: Please don't post images of plain text — put the text into the question between a line containing `\`\`\`none` and another containing `\`\`\``.

Comment: In standard C, a stream has an [orientation](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2p4) — wide or byte.  Once it has an operation performed on a stream, its orientation is fixed.  You can't change between byte-oriented functions such as `printf()` and wide-oriented functions such as `wprintf()`.  The input and output orientations are independent.  The chances are that you're using a codeset that uses multiple bytes to represent accented characters.  Print the integer value of `choix`.  Also, capture and print the value returned from `getchar()` — it probably isn't `'\n'`.

Comment: @jonathan : 
VS permitted a lot of thing in C... In this case, that's just a prog for testing, but, in some way, you have wrigth, I souldn't discard standard because "I'm just testing" ;)

If I add 
'''
SetConsoleCP(1252);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
'''
It's work, but that's not explain why the setlocale is not enough :/

Comment: There are lots of details to worry about. I'm not familiar enough with the way Windows handles locale-related issues to be able to help much more.  I think you need to ensure that you know what codeset you're using.  If it is a Unicode 16-bit code set (UTF-16 or UCS-2), reading single bytes won't work reliably.  Setting CP-1252 changes to a single-byte codeset, of course.  That's part of why you need to print the integer values for the data that's read as well as the character representations.  I don't know how critical wide-orientation vs byte-orientation is on Windows; it matters on Unix.

Comment: Incidentally, note that code is formatted between back-ticks `\`\`\`` (though one is sufficient), not single quotes `'''`.  And in a comment, you need to type `\`\\`\\`\\`\`` to display backticks.

Comment: SharaKym, Tip: In debugging output, use sentinel characters to to better discern whitespace and true output.  `printf("%c\n", choix); ... printf("%s\n\n", buffer);` --> `printf("<%c>\n", choix); ... printf("<%s>\n\n", buffer);`

Comment: Mixing narrow and wide calls certainly a recipe for failure. `wscanf(L" %lc", &wchoix); ... getchar();` makes little sense.  Choose 1: narrow or wide.

Comment: I don't want to mix, i search fort the one will work so I test all before finding.
At the end, I will use only narrow or wide, dependeing of who's working with accent.

Answer (score 1):

So if I change the code to printf the integer value of all:

```
int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("%s\n\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, ""));
    char buffer[50], choix;
    int i;

    printf("CHAR\nEntrez un char : ");
    scanf(" %c", &choix);
    printf("choix user : %c -> %d\n", choix, choix);
    choix = getchar();
    printf("choix getchar : %c -> %d\n", choix, choix);

    printf("Entrez votre éùàç prénom : ");
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    printf("buffer : %s -> ", buffer);
    for (i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++)
        printf("%d ", buffer[i]);
    printf("\n");
    choix = getchar();
    printf("choix getchar : %c -> %d\n", choix, choix);
    
    wchar_t wbuffer[50], wchoix;

    printf("\n\nWCHAR\nEntrez un char : ");
    wscanf(L" %lc", &wchoix);
    wprintf(L"wchar : %lc - 0x%04x\n", wchoix, wchoix);
    choix = getchar();
    printf("choix getchar : %c -> %d\n", choix, choix);

    wprintf(L"Entrez votre éùàç prénom : ");
    wscanf(L"%ls", wbuffer);
    wprintf(L"wbuffer : %ls -> ", wbuffer);
    for (i = 0; wbuffer[i] != '\0'; i++)
        wprintf(L"0x%04x ", wbuffer[i]);
    printf("\n");
    choix = getchar();
    printf("choix getchar : %c -> %d\n", choix, choix);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The console show :
[image: result in cmd]

If I see the CP850/CP1252 table :
-126 = 130 -> é / '
10 -> LF ( \n )

in wchar, if it's Unicode
0x201a -> ' (é it's 0x00E9)

Then I receive from stdin a CP850 code and printf a CP1252 one....
There's no other solution to solve this except the SetConsoleCP/SetConsoleOutputCP from windows.h  (or system("CHCP 1252))?
The setlocale don't change the 'stdin' from CP850 (default win consol) to CP1252?

At the end, I will do it all in English, it's more simple. ;)

---

I try another thing that's seem to confirm that the setlocal don't modify the console :

[image: cmd chcp]

Same result with "setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1252");". The SetConsole seem to be unavoidable :/

Answer (score 0):

In final, the better compromise I found :
[image: portable code]

Using narrow or wide, this is the only way that's work.

thanks to all for the help in the reflexion ;)